# Проблема с BufferedReader readline()

Tags: java

Решаю задачи с JavaRush и проблема в том, что через BufferedReader подчеркивает красным дужки после  readLine(); ,хотя через Scanner  nextLine()  всё хорошо.В чем же сообственно трабла. Ошибка: unreported exception IOException;must be caught or declared to be thrown

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    String name = reader.readLine();
    int count1 = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int count2 = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    System.out.println(name + "получает" + count1 + "через" + "лет.");
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы должны либо обернуть ваш код в конструкцию `try {} catch (IOException e) { }` или же декларировать в методе `throw IOException`.

Почитать про `checked exception` можно [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/company/golovachcourses/blog/225585/)

Comment: Спасибо,теперь понял)